# Problem with train_test split scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was working for the following classification task using Random Forests classifier.

```
No. of classes = 11
Y = 50
X = 100
```

I used 75% train and 25% test.

However, when I calculated the confusion matrix, a diagonal value (27) is higher than 25.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(test_Y, y_prediction)
print (conf_matrix)

[[17  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1 12  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0]
 [ 0  0 22  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 16  0 12  1  0  0  0  1]
 [ 0  1  0  0 19  0  0  0  6  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  7  0 18  2  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 20  1  0  0  0]
 [ 2  2  2  0  0  0  0 27  0  3  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  8  1  0  0 13  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 16  4]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 12 14]]
```

When I explored the reason, the train test split is not doing as expected.

```
yy, counts = np.unique(Y, return_counts=True)
print (yy, counts)

[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10] [100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100]

train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y  = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

#### But,

```
yy, counts = np.unique(test_Y, return_counts=True)
print (yy, counts)

[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10] [19 21 24 30 26 27 21 36 22 22 27]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nope, they are not all 25 after train_test split; but they had to be. Is not it?

They have not to be, because you have not asked for a **stratified** train/test split; change it to:

```
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y  = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, 
                                                     stratify=Y,
                                                     random_state=42)
```

Comment: Ah, i did not know that. What it does with out `stratify=Y`.

Comment: Is it matter of new version?

Comment: @mk1 it maintains the analogy of the labels in the split; not sure it is a matter of version, check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).